# Feedback on short film...

Tags: film, boom, sound-design, feedback

Last September I worked as a boom operator on "Eyes to See".  It was the first actual film I worked on having previously worked only in various video formats. You can check it out at [thedoorpost.com](http://www.thedoorpost.com/).  Just wanted to see what people thought of the dialogue clarity as well as the SFX and sound design.

It's kind of long so I understand if you only want to watch a short part of it.  Looking forward to feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you did a great job on the capturing the dialogue. It was very clear and the voices had a lot of depth to them. What microphone(s) did you use? 
On another note I thought the sound designer did a great job capturing the atmosphere of what was going on in the film.

Comment: The sound mixer chose to use an MKH416 on the boom and MKE2's hooked up to Senn G2's for wireless.  We got extra range from the G2's by using various lengths of XLR to get the receivers closer to the transmitters.  The sound mixer actually got to travel to Haiti and record some SFX for the film over there which I thought were utilized well by the sound designer.  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @bpert, would love to hear those Haiti recordings. Any chance you'd be willing to post some to SoundCloud?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to watch a short part of this and give some feedback but I found myself 20 minutes in before I knew it.  The voices are very clear and the ambience well placed in the mix.  Very nice!

I also would love to hear more Haiti recordings as well....Soundcloud?